# user script localStorage loop - improve performance

Tags: jquery, for-loop, local-storage, userscripts

I wrote a userscript for a cms my company is using. It uses sass so there is a huge form where we have to enter the css params.

My script stores all the params in localStorage and then reenters it in a different website's css form.

The script works fine but the performance is really bad. So maybe someone can help me to improve this script.

So this is the basic html markup of one form-field:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="1_1249_0">table_color: <span>#424242</span></label>
<input type="text" id="1_1249_0" name="1_1249_0" size="40" class="form-control" value="#424242"><input type="hidden" name="templateconfigfieldname_1249" value="table_color">
</div>
```

This loop stores the form in local Storage

```
jQuery('.form-group label').next().not('div').parent().children('.form-group label').each(function() {
            labeltext = jQuery(this).clone().children().remove().end().text();
            params = jQuery(this).children('span').text();
            localStorage.setItem(labeltext,params);
        });
```

And this is the loop which retrieves the content from the localStorage:

```
for (var i = 0; i < numberofParams; i++){
      params = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i));
      labeltext = localStorage.key(i);
      jQuery('.form-group label').filter(function() {
      return jQuery(this).clone().children().remove().end().text() === labeltext;}).next('input, select').val(params);
      }
```

Comment: The performance is bad because you use too much jQuery. All the DOM traversals are pretty heavy if there are many elements. I recommend reimplement it without jQuery or with minimum of it. In three lines of code you used like all jQuery methods available :) Pretty sure it can be simpler. Maybe post the same question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle,I'll try simplying it .http://jsfiddle.net